# How to check if an association changed from nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to do something every time certain properties on a model change:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :vendor

  before_save :do_stuff_if_dirty

  def do_stuff_if_dirty
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'zipcode']

    if fields.any? { |field| (self.send("#{field}_changed?".to_sym)) }
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

I would also like to do stuff when the associated vendor changes from `nil` to an instance of `Vendor`. But because this is an association, I cannot call `user.vendor_changed?`. How can I check if the association was made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `before_save` on the `Vendor` model, that calls a method on the `User` it should solve your problem.

It depends on the relationships between Vendor and User, but you should be able to check `vendor_id_changed?` or `user_id_changed?` on one of the models, if not a join table